# NullPointerException when app goes in background having OnBoarding opened

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My Xamarin.Android application has an OnBoarding process that starts from the MainActivity.
Each time I minimize the application and try to start it again, I am presented in the output with NullPointerException and I cannot find the root cause.

```
10-30 13:52:59.102 W/System.err(23618): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
10-30 13:52:59.102 W/System.err(23618):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.getHostVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:1809)
10-30 13:52:59.102 W/System.err(23618):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleAppVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:1445)
10-30 13:52:59.102 W/System.err(23618):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
10-30 13:52:59.102 W/System.err(23618):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
10-30 13:52:59.103 W/System.err(23618):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
10-30 13:52:59.103 W/System.err(23618):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
10-30 13:52:59.103 W/System.err(23618):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 13:52:59.103 W/System.err(23618):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
10-30 13:52:59.103 W/System.err(23618):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
10-30 13:53:01.421 W/ActivityThread(23618): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@177ac90
10-30 13:53:01.473 I/DecorView(23618): createDecorCaptionView >> DecorView@a2ae0c1[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
```

The OnBoarding is created using AppIntro class and it is called from MainActivity like this:

```
 private bool CanOpenOnBoarding()
        {
            var getPrefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseContext);
            bool isFirstStart = getPrefs.GetBoolean(AppDetails.ShowOnboarding, true);
            if (isFirstStart)
            {
                StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(OnBoarding)));
                Finish();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

The OnCreate of the MainActivity is:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            MainViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnProprietyChanged;

            Presenter = (CustomPresenter) Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>();
            Presenter.RegisterFragmentManager(FragmentManager);

            var appService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IApplicationService>();
            appService.InitializeDbAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            MainViewModel.CheckForConnectivityAsync();

            if (CanOpenOnBoarding())
            {
                return;
            }

            TabHost = FindViewById<TabHost>(global::Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
            TabHost.TabWidget.SetDividerDrawable(null);
            TabHost.Setup();

            //leave them without Await
            MainViewModel.DisplayTermsAndConditionsModalAsync();
        }
```

The others lifecycles are not hit (OnResume, OnPause).
Each time I resume the app, I am navigated to MainActivity`s OnCreate method, where I am starting again the OnBoarding Activity.

The application is not crashing, as I can see it from the Recent Apps.
How can I find and fix the root cause of the NullPointerException?

Comment: Can you show the code where the exception happens?

Comment: I don`t know where the exception happens

Comment: Do crashes occur only after the app has been put to the background and then resumed?

Comment: Sometimes the NullPointerException happens also when I press on "Recent Apps" button and sometimes when I got back from minimized.

Comment: share you onResumed() onStart() onStop() and onPaused() code then, or perhaps easier jsut to share the whole mainActivity code

Comment: the stacktrace you shared does not show any lines of code in your app are the problem (directly). Have you tried on another device, or tried using other apps on that device. To prove it's actually your problem?

Comment: I used the app on another device and the NullPointerException is happening too but the difference is that is not so visible.

Comment: I'd put some if(something == null) Log... so you can see in the output more info, I'd check if `MainViewModel` is null before using it, also `TabHost`, `getPrefs`, `Presenter`, `appService` and also enclose in a `try...catch` the `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve` and log the ex in the catch just in case